# How to improve make and make install's speed in centos?

Tags: makefile, centos, make-install

Sometimes use make and make install mysql or python, the process of those are very slow.
how cloud i speed up the process of make or make install in centos?

Answer (score 1):

`make -j$(nproc)` will run compilation using multiple cores, if available.

The `nproc` reports number of CPU cores, and the `-j` flag to `make` will run compilation in parallel.

P.S. you better not compile anything by hand in CentOS and stick to RPM packaging, which will usually have spec files which make use of the above mentioned parallel compilation.

By hand-compiling stuff in an Community *Enterprise* OS, you're essentially turning it to something that it's not. (hand compiling will result in not enterprise, insecure, outdated software, sooner or later).

Comment: thanks Danila. when i compile kernel, i always use  "make -j $(nproc)". For others，i never use make ,make install rpm with those parameter. After that then, i will test it. Maybe the compile  installation depends on your business type, don't worry about it
. thanks again.